# are there different ways of importing git repository to Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, git, github

Why when I import a git project it does not appear like full package path view (*main.java.comformance*) like this image:

[image: Current at left, expected at right]

I have imported this project before but now in the package view, it only appears as a tree of folders and not full package path view like *main.java.comformance* with package icons. I wonder what I'm doing differently now. I followed the instructions in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L8IeaWHZCRo)?

Comment: In the image I see a "com.tst.org", so I guess you miss to upload some other image about what actually you see?

Comment: @AlfonsoNishikawa I uploaded a new picture

Comment: This sounds like an Eclipse configuration issue that has nothing to do with Git or GitHub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both projects on the screenshot do not seem to be configured correctly (probably because they were not created with Eclipse or files like `.project` were not shared):

- The project on the **right side is obviously a Maven project** (with probably this [`pom.xml`](https://github.com/owlcs/jfact/blob/version5/pom.xml) file): the Java source folder should be `src/main/java/` (default of Maven) instead of `src` (default of Eclipse) and the Java packages for instance `uk.ac.manchester.cs.jfact` instead of `main.java.uk.ac.manchester.cs.jfact`.
- The project on the **left side is not even configured as a Java project**.

The simplest way is to use the Eclipse [Smart Import](https://github.com/owlcs/jfact/blob/version5/pom.xml) feature (instead of configure everything manually): the Java nature of the project will be detected even without the `.project` file and also the `pom.xml` file is read to get the required JARs and to configure the Java build path and source folder(s) automatically:

1. **Clone** the Git repository
2. In the ***Git Repositories*** view **right-click** the ***Working Tree*** node and choose ***Import Projects...***

Answer (score 0):

Do you see the "J" in the icon next to the project name "jfact" at the right image?
That means that it is a "java" project. Eclipse does not know anything about your project.

You will have to do one of this:

- Checkout the project again with Eclipse and use a "wizard" configuring it as a java project.
- Enable Project Facets (right-click on the project name), and then enable "Java" in the Project Properties/Facets. This is not trivial, so I don't recommend this. - If this is a solution, actually I don't know for sure -
- If you are using maven, close the project and execute `mvn eclipse:eclipse` to convert/create the project files for eclipse, and open again the project.

After you manage it to become a Java project, furter steps could be needed, but maybe will be enough.